Filter and sort data with multiple column & row criteria and then match corresponding data to it with multiple flexible return_arrays



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O




1
Product

Shop

2023-S
2023-M

2024-S
2024-M

Type






2

















3







500









4


P-Line_A









Step1




5
Prod_A

shop3

80
2%

500
22%

t1

ColCrit1
ColCrit2
ColCrit3


6
Prod_B

shop2

320
23%

180
60%

t1

Prod_D
shop1
t3


7
Prod_B

shop1

90
8%

300
36%

t2

Prod_G
shop3
t4


8
Prod_C

shop3

500
15%

657
16%

t1


shop4



9
Prod_D

shop1

160
17%

500
15%

t3






10
Prod_D

shop1

500
30%

600
8%

t3

rowCrit




11
Prod_D

shop1

130
4%

300
4%

t3

2024-S




12
Total



1810


3037









13

















14







600




Step2




15







300




lookup_array
ret_array1
ret_array2


16


P-Line_B









2024-S
Product
Type


17
Prod_E

shop2

75
10%

450
10%

t1






18
Prod_F

shop4

60
8%

370
4%

t2






19
Prod_F

shop1

500
11%

850
4%

t2

Step3




20
Prod_G

shop3

350
8%

150
15%

t3

Rows
Start



21
Prod_G

shop3

60
47%

600
7%

t4

10
2



22
Prod_G

shop4

90
25%

830
35%

t4






23
Prod_G

shop2

390
9%

325
13%

t1






24
Prod_G

shop3

90
30%

300
9%

t3

Step4




25
Prod_G

shop4

90
5%

300
12%

t3

Product
Type
2024-S


26
Prod_G

shop4

120
24%

300
24%

t4

Prod_D
t3
600


27
Prod_G

shop4

135
35%

480
17%

t4

Prod_G
t4
600


28
Prod_H

shop2

935
27%

230
16%

t1

Prod_D
t3
500


29
Prod_I

shop3

134
18%

600
42%

t2

Prod_G
t4
480


30
Total



3029


5785




Prod_D
t3
300


31












Prod_G
t3
300


32












Prod_G
t3
300


33












Prod_G
t4
300


34












Prod_G
t3
150


35

















36



















Target
The final Output is Range M26:O34 which is a descending list based on the lookup_array in Cell M16 and multiple column and row filters (Range M6:M8, Range N6:O8, Range O6:O8 and Cell M11) and selected positions in the rank based on Cell M21 and Cell N21.
To get this list the following steps are required: 
(You can also see the steps in the table in Column M so it is easier to follow the instructions)

Define multiple column criteria in Range M6:O6 and a row criteria in Cell M11. These criteria are all AND criteria. After filtering the list it should be sorted descending.
Based on Step1 you will have a descending list fulfilling the column and row criteria. For this list the corresponding values based on ret_array1 in Cell N16 and ret_array2  in Cell O16 should be added.  (Note: lookup_array = rowCrit --> Cell M16 = Cell M11)
From the list in Step2 only the values that are ranked in positions based on Cell M21 and Cell N21 should be displayed.  In this case the 10 positions after the 1st position.
After Step1-3 in Step4 the final list should appear.

Therefore, summarized I need these two formulas:
Formula 1: Getting a descending list considering multiple criteria and only display certain positions from this list. 
Fromula 2: Getting the corresponding data to it based on multiple flexible return_arrays. 

Current Status
With help from previous questions I have been able to apply these two formulas: 
1. Getting the required list 
Answer from this question
=TOCOL(INDEX(SORT(
    LET(
    a,COUNTIF(M6:M8,A1:A31)+AND(M6:M8=""),
    b,COUNTIF(N6:N8,C1:C31)+AND(N6:N8=""),
    c,COUNTIF(O6:O8,K1:K31)+AND(O6:O8=""),
    FILTER(FILTER(A1:K31,(A1:K1=M11),""),a*b*c,"")),,-1),SEQUENCE(M21,,N21)),2)

This formula already works perfectly without any issue.
2. Getting the correspondig data 
Answer from this question
SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOL(A1:K30,
         XMATCH(M16,A1:K1),
         XMATCH(N16,A1:K1),
         XMATCH(O16,A1:K1)),
             (AND(M6:M8="")+COUNTIF(M6:M8,A1:A30))*
             (AND(N6:N8="")+COUNTIF(N6:N8,C1:C30))*
             (AND(O6:O8="")+COUNTIF(O6:O8,K1:K30)),""),,-1)

This formula almost gives me the correct result. 

Question
Regarding the second formula I do not know how to apply SEQUENCE to it and how to order the columns so they match with the desired result displayed in the above table.
What I like about both formulas is that it is very easy to chain additional column criteria to them since in my orginal file I have even more. It would be great to keep this flexibility.
Do you have any idea how to solve the issue?

Try: =LET(     a,COUNTIF(M6:M8,A1:A31)+AND(M6:M8=""),     b,COUNTIF(N6:N8,C1:C31)+AND(N6:N8=""),     c,COUNTIF(O6:O8,K1:K31)+AND(O6:O8=""),     WRAPROWS(TOCOL(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(A1:K31,XMATCH(HSTACK(N16,O16,M16),A1:K1)),FILTER(A1:K31,A1:K1=M11,"")),a*b*c,""),3,-1),SEQUENCE(M21,,N21),{1,2,3}),2),3))

Try :


=LET(
    _a, COUNTIF(M6:M8,A1:A31)+AND(M6:M8=""),
    _b, COUNTIF(N6:N8,C1:C31)+AND(N6:N8=""),
    _c, COUNTIF(O6:O8,K1:K31)+AND(O6:O8=""),
    _d, CHOOSECOLS(A1:K31,XMATCH(HSTACK(N16,O16,M16),A1:K1)),
    _e, SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(_d,FILTER(A1:K31,A1:K1=M11,"")),_a*_b*_c,""),3,-1),
    WRAPROWS(TOCOL(INDEX(_e,SEQUENCE(M21,,N21),{1,2,3}),2),3))


Depending on the language that you are using in your Excel the {1,2,3} might be entered as {1.2.3} to make it work.
For example in German Excel the formula works like this:
=LET(
    _a; ZÄHLENWENN(M6:M8;A1:A31)+UND(M6:M8="");
    _b; ZÄHLENWENN(N6:N8;C1:C31)+UND(N6:N8="");
    _c; ZÄHLENWENN(O6:O8;K1:K31)+UND(O6:O8="");
    _d; SPALTENWAHL(A1:K31;XVERGLEICH(HSTAPELN(N16;O16;M16);A1:K1));
    _e; SORTIEREN(FILTER(HSTAPELN(_d;FILTER(A1:K31;A1:K1=M11;""));_a*_b*_c;"");3;-1);
    ZEILENUMBRUCH(ZUSPALTE(INDEX(_e;SEQUENZ(M21;;N21);{1.2.3});2);3))

Alternatively replacing {1.2.3} with SEQUENZ(;3) also works:
=LET(
    _a; ZÄHLENWENN(M6:M8;A1:A31)+UND(M6:M8="");
    _b; ZÄHLENWENN(N6:N8;C1:C31)+UND(N6:N8="");
    _c; ZÄHLENWENN(O6:O8;K1:K31)+UND(O6:O8="");
    _d; SPALTENWAHL(A1:K31;XVERGLEICH(HSTAPELN(N16;O16;M16);A1:K1));
    _e; SORTIEREN(FILTER(HSTAPELN(_d;FILTER(A1:K31;A1:K1=M11;""));_a*_b*_c;"");3;-1);
    ZEILENUMBRUCH(ZUSPALTE(INDEX(_e;SEQUENZ(M21;;N21);SEQUENZ(;3));2);3))



See question in edited answer.

@Michi will it ok for you, if i post an excel? Why is it returning only one line on your end? Is there any spaces on your data or something?

For me is ok if you post an Excel.

@Michi Are those numbers 10 and 2 true numbers?

Yes, these are numbers. I just aligned them to the left.

@Michi you can download from here: link

First guess from me is that this part {1;2;3} could cause the issue. In German Excel format I need to change from "," to ";" in the formula. Probably, in this part of the formula I need to stay with ",". However, when I change this part to "," an Excel error message pops up: "There's a problem with this formula". What is also weird is that when I open your link the name of the formulas are translated to German but the "," stays and the formula works. See Screenshot3 which I attached.

@Michi hmmm try to make it . or / may be this. easy way to detect in some cell write . 1,2,3 and use HSTACK() to merge, next select the HSTACK() formula and hit F9 or on selection it will show up the separator you would need to use

@Michi or use in place of {1,2,3} --> SEQUENCE(;3) --> SEQUENZ(;3)

The change to the "." worked. Upvote for extra help from my side.

@Michi sounds good, i have commented alternate option instead of hard-coding using SEQUENZ()

Thanks. It also works. I added it to the answer as well.

@Michi fixed the typo from SEQUENCE() to SEQUENZ()
